# Can CXF publish wsdls and xsd as the original separate files instead of one big file?

Tags: cxf, soapui

I have generated a CXF webservice using a WSDL and several XSD files (top-down approach).

But when I open a browser pointing at my CXF webservice http://some-ip/path/WebServiceName?wsdl it returns a big WSDL file (the original XSD objects are all included in this file).

Is it possible to configure CXF in a way that publishes the original WSDL and XSD files in separate files (with `<import>`) instead of one big file?

With the big file, I am getting the following error with SoapUI "Validate": 
Expected element 'someElement@someNamespace' instead of 'someElement@someOtherNamespace' here in element ...

It looks like the namespaces are somehow mixed (either in the WDSL generated by CXF or the "Validate" function of SoapUI).

But the problem is only with the WSDL returned by CXF (the url ending with '?wsdl') because the problem is not there if I import into SoapUI the original WSDL and XSD from my hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.setWsdlLocation`
with the path to your WSDL on the classpath, the service will publish a WSDL with the XML schema files imported.

Example, with Spring annotations:

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleWebServiceConfiguration {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "/*";
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME_LOCAL_PART = "ExampleService";
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME_NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.org/webservices/1.0/ExampleService";

    protected ExampleServicePortType ExampleServicePortType;

    @Value("${ws.endpoint.address}")
    String wsEndpointAddress;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleWebServiceConfiguration(ExampleServicePortType ExampleServicePortType) {
        this.ExampleServicePortType = ExampleServicePortType;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), BASE_URL);
    }

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), ExampleServicePortType);
        endpoint.setServiceName(new QName(SERVICE_NAME_NAMESPACE_URI, SERVICE_NAME_LOCAL_PART));
        endpoint.setWsdlLocation("/wsdl/exampleservices/ExampleService.wsdl");
        endpoint.publish(wsEndpointAddress);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```